# Error when trying to sendmail An error occured while fetching the JSON data: HTTP 0 status code

Tags: joomla-4.x

On Joomla! 4.1.3 i have set the mail settings the first time i have tried with gmail SMTP and the second time with office365 smtp in both case i'am not able to send mail.

When i hit the button "Send test mail" no messages appear and no mails is send, if i hit close button i have this error appear when i'am redirected : `An error occured while fetching the JSON data: HTTP 0 status code`

I have enabled debug in Joomla! configuration panel and the error reporting is set to maximum

How to know what is going on ?

The server behind it's on debian 11 : php7.4.28, apache2

Comment: Are there any related messages in the log files? Check /administrator/logos/ for the general log or  a specific log for config or emails if they have been created.

Comment: I have the following files under /administrator/logs/  but nothing related :  1.error.php last edit jan 5, 1.jcontroller.log.php last edit jan 7, 1.joomla_update.php last edit jan 4 and joomla_update.php last edit on may 15

Comment: I have the same problem with the google workspace account on the Inmotion server. As far as I reached with my search the JSON file could be repaired through PHPmyadmin, on different tables.
The challenge now is to find which table needs to be fixed.